# undefined method nil:NilClass ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I need to do is create a page where the user will type in a last name and the system will return information related to it. I keep receiving the error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass." I am stuck and can not debug it any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

CODE FOR THE INPUT PAGE

```
<%= form_tag(showcustcourses_custcoursesout_path, :controller => "showcustcourses", :action => "custcoursesout", :method => "post") do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :Customer_Name %><br />
    <%= text_field_tag :customer_name_in %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit Customer Name" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

CODE FOR THE CONTROLLER

```
class BookinController < ApplicationController

  def bookin
  end

  def bookout
    @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in]
    @r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
    @rate_list = @r ? @r.rates : nil
  end
end
```

CODE FOR THE OUTPUT PAGE (`<% @customer_list.each do |m| %>` is throwing the error)

```
<h1>Bookin#bookout</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/bookin/bookout.html.erb</p>

<center><table width = 65% border = 1> 
  <tr> <th> Customer Name</th><th> Room Number </th>  <th> Cost </th></tr>   
  <% @customer_list.each do |m| %>
    <tr> <td> <%= m.name %> </td> <td> <%= m.roomnumber %> </td> <td> <%= m.cost %> </td> </tr> 
  <% end %>
</table> </center><br /> <br />
```

Comment: @customer_list is nil

Comment: Where you defined `@customer_list` in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` because you forgot to set the value of instance variable `@customer_list`. So, `@customer_list` is `nil`.

You need to set `@customer_list` variable in the **action corresponding to your view** which in your case is `bookout` action as you are rendering `bookout.html.erb`.

Simply, do this in `BookinController#bookout`:

```
  def bookout
    ## ...
    @customer_list = Customer.all ## Add this
  end
```

**UPDATE**

As per the chat discussion, OP needed to show last(from customers table), roomlevel(from apples table), cost(from rates table)

Suggested to modify

`bookout` method as below:

```
def bookout 
  @customer_list = Customer.all 
  @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in] 
end
```

and `bookout.html.erb` as below:

```
<% @customer_list.each do |customer| %> 
  <% customer.bookings.each do |booking| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td> <%= customer.last %> </td> 
    <td> <%= booking.apple.room_level %> </td> 
    <td> <%= booking.apple.cost %> </td> 
  </tr> 
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Also, OP's schema was not correct to achieve this result. Added `apple_id` to `bookings` table and removed `rate_id` from it.

**NOTE:** As you don't want bookings to be associated with `rates` table,`rate_id`was removed from `bookings` table. You would have to add `cost` field in `apples` table to display the cost in the view.

Comment: Hello Thank you for the answer I have done that and it still returns the error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass. I dont understand it because I have a customer table

Comment: Do you have any records in Customer table? Just goto the `rails console` and type `Customer.all` and see what you get as output. Let me know.

Comment: The following is what is found when I typed in Customer.all into the command prompt

Comment: irb(main):001:0> Customer.all
  Customer Load (10.0ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Customer id: 2, first: "Chris", last: "Helgeson",

>

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your controller. It will  bring details of all customers.

```
def bookin
   @customer_list = Customer.all 
end

def bookout
  @customer_list = Customer.all 
  @customer_name = params[:customer_name_in]
  @r = Customer.find_by_last(@customer_name)
  @rate_list = @r ? @r.rates : nil
end
```

If still it returns nil error, then it means you do not have any customer records in database.

```
<h1>Bookin#bookout</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/bookin/bookout.html.erb</p>

 <center><table width = 65% border = 1> 
 <tr> <th> Customer Name</th><th> Room Number </th>  <th> Cost </th></tr>   
  #check if object is not nil
 <% if !@customer_list.nil? %>
   <% @customer_list.each do |m| %>
    <tr> 
      <td> <%= m.name %> </td> 
      <td> <%= m.roomnumber %> </td> 
      <td> <%= m.cost %>      
     </td> 
    </tr> 
    <% end %>

  <% else %>
   <p> no customers available </p>
  <% end %>

  </table>
  </center>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I am just very confused because I have a table named customer with entries in it. Im not sure why it can not find it

Comment: did above code solved your problem ?  if not what is error now ?

Comment: It is still not returning any customers when I go into the console it say there is a customer table irb(main):001:0> Customer.all
  Customer Load (10.0ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Customer id: 2, first: "Chris", last: "Helgeson",

>

Answer (score 0):

@customer_list is not defined

defined it in controller like this

@customer_list = Customer.all